Is conditional expectation evaluated by the copula strictly increasing when the correlation coefficient is positive and vice versa?
I used the copula to evaluate the $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ and from my experiments on some copulas, I observed that when the random variables have positive correlation coefficient, $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ is strictly increasing and when they are negatively correlated $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ is strictly decreasing. Also, the conditional expectation plots in this post show the strict behavior too. I'm wondering if this is true and how to prove it.

Unless you're leaving out some condition, the answer is no.
For example, let $c=\Phi(1)\approx 0.8413$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf. Consider the bivariate copula that corresponds to $V=1-U$ for $1-c<U<c$ and $V=U$ otherwise, where $U$ is standard uniform. The correlation of $U$ and $V$ is positive (roughly 0.36), but $E(V|U=u)$ is decreasing when $u$ is in that middle section.
Now let $X=\Phi^{-1}(U)$ and $Y=\Phi^{-1}(V)$; $(X,Y)$ has the same copula. Now for $(X,Y)$ the Pearson correlation is higher (around 0.6) but again the conditional expectation function is not strictly increasing.

The value of $c$ is not special; I simply chose it because it was fairly clear that the correlation in the Gaussian margins case would be positive. For the copula itself (uniform margins), any positive $c$ less than about 0.8968 works, for the Gaussian margins case positive $c$ less than about 0.938 works. You could choose a convenient value of $c$ and compute an exact correlation on the copula if you wanted.
